# AngularJS - use custom service within controller

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

What is the correct way to inject a service into a controller in Angular?

I have written a service and i’d like to use it in my controllers. But i keep getting an error. Maybe it would be easy for someone to spot my mistake…

authController.js

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
       .module('authApp')
       .service('authService', function($auth, $state, $http, $rootScope, envService,   $scope) {
          // some code 
        })
       .controller('SignupController', SignupController, ['$scope', 'authService’]);

       function SignupController($http, $scope, $rootScope, $location, envService, authService) {
          // want to use my authService here 
       }

 ...
```

At this point I get the following error :

> angular.js:12477 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- authService

What is wrong with the way I have injected authService into my signupController??

Thanks.

Comment: `$scope` isn't injectable in `service`, also you have messed `SignupController ` controller DI array and sequence in controller function

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense about $scope! >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error declaring your controller. Declaring a controller with the array syntax receives the name of the controller as a String as first parameter, and an array as a second parameter. The last element of the array must be the a function with all the controller logic. That function must have as many parameters as previous elements in the array itself. In your case it should be something like:

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
       .module('authApp')
       .service('authService', function($auth, $state, $http, $rootScope, envService,   $scope) {
          // some code 
        })
       .controller('SignupController', ['$http', '$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', 'envService', 'authService',  function ($http, $scope, $rootScope, $location, envService, authService) {
          // Use your authService here 
       }]);
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manual-annotating-for-dependency-injection) to write your controllers, services and inject your dependencies in a better way.

Comment: I'm aware of the documentation, but I don't really know what i'm looking for. Hence the question.